# SQL server change table query not working as expected

Tags: sql-server-2008

It looks like that a CHANGETABLE query for a particular table is not working correctly.

I created a record in the bill_details table and then updated it.
The record was created with sys_change_version=5000.
The records was updated with sys_change_version=5001.

But the following CHANGETABLE queries are confusing me and apparently returning incorrect sys_change_creation_version:

```
select * from CHANGETABLE(CHANGES bill_details, 5000) ct  order by bill_id;


sys_change_version       sys_change_creation_version        sys_change_operation       sys_change_columns     sys_change_context     bill_id
-------------------      -----------------------------      ----------------------     -------------------    --------------------   --------
5001                     5001                                U                          NULL                   NULL                   2018





select * from CHANGETABLE(CHANGES bill_details, 4999) ct  order by bill_id;


sys_change_version       sys_change_creation_version        sys_change_operation       sys_change_columns     sys_change_context     bill_id
-------------------      -----------------------------      ----------------------     -------------------    --------------------   --------
5001                     5001                                I                          NULL                   NULL                   2018
```

I would expect that if the sys_change_operation is 'U' then the sys_change_creation_version would be NULL.
And if a record is updated and if I am searching using a smaller 'from version' number then the sys_change_version and sys_change_creation_versions would be different.

Any ideas what I am missing? Or why these CHANGETABLE queries are behaving in an unexpected manner?

Regards.